# What are the real-time applications of `const volatile` type qualifier?

Tags: c, embedded

What are the real-time applications of `const volatile` type qualifier? In which scenario would one use this.  I know the applications of `volatile` keyword & `const` qualifiers, but I don't understand the usage of `const volatile` together. Please share yours thoughts.

Comment: http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/barr-code/4236917/Combining-C-s-volatile-and-const-keywords

Comment: Neither the`volatile` nor the `const` qualifier are related to real-time.

Comment: @Olaf - perhaps he meant "real-world"?

Comment: There are three scenarios regarding the use of these qualifiers together; these are not really addressed in the "duplicate" (which is not really a duplicate, even if the answer is applicable).

Comment: @Clifford: Speculation. There is sooo much confusion about what RT means. The term is even missused in commercials. We are no clairvoyants.

Comment: @Olaf : Indeed but at least "real-world" would make some kind of sense, but given the tag "embedded",  he may equally be conflating "real-time" with "multi-threaded" (and in an RTOS).  The purpose of my "speculation" was to encourage the author to improve the question - addressing it to you was entirely rhetorical.  It is disappointing when the original authors do not engage - as if they are not really interested in the answer to their own question.

Comment: @Clifford: I prefer taking such questions literally. I'd say as asked, the question is too broad. There is a plethora of RT applications using such variables. Talking about embedded: a short look into an MCU header likely shows already some examples.

Answer (score 3):

`const` and `volatile` can be combined in three ways to different and useful effect.  Examples:

1. To declare a constant address of a hardware register:

   ```
   uint8_t volatile* const p_led_reg = (uint8_t *) 0x80000;
   ```
2. To declare a read-only inter-processor shared-memory, where the other processor is the writer:

   ```
   int const volatile comm_flag;

   uint8_t const volatile comm_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   ```
3. To declare a read-only hardware register:

   ```
   uint8_t const volatile* const p_latch_reg = (uint8_t *) 0x10000000;
   ```

Note that type qualifiers in each of these cases are:

- `volatile* const` - Constant address to variable volatile data.
- `const volatile` - Read-only volatile data.
- `const volatile* const` - Constant address to read-only volatile data.

A complete description of these usages is provided in Michael Barr's Embedded.com article [Combining C's volatile and const keywords](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/barr-code/4236917/3/Combining-C-s-volatile-and-const-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.3 Type qualifiers) gives an example:

> EXAMPLE 1 An object declared
>
> ```
> extern const volatile int real_time_clock;
> ```
>
> may be modifiable by hardware, but cannot be assigned to, incremented, or decremented.

This tells the C compiler that although the program can't modify the real time clock, the real time clock can change and therefore must be treated with circumspection when optimizing code that references it.